# Set website to display in 150px by 150px in an iframe

Tags: html

I have the code

```
<iframe width=150px height=150px src=http://yahoo.com></iframe>
```

Here I will have a 150x150 iframe, but I want the whole site to be reduced to a 150x150.

Is it possible to do it.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Not really (read: not cross browser).  Internet Explorer supports the `zoom` CSS property which might work, but AFAIK no other browsers support it.

From the details you've given it looks like you're trying to get a thumbnail of a site.  Have you considered using a thumbnail preview service like [WebSnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/) or [SnapCasa](http://snapcasa.com/SampleSnap.aspx?u=http://google.com)?